# php/mysql : error sending query to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have sent queries to mysql databases a lot so it threw me for a loop when this stopped working. I'm just trying to insert text and int and decimal information. Is the syntax wrong somewhere? It throws this error message, but I dont know what it means!

Errormessage:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) VALUES (jpeg.jpg,1410700,image/jpeg,1372713379,42.978852222222,-86.0356041' at line 1
```

name, type, datetime table columns are varchar

size is int

lat and long are decimals(14,12) and (15,12)

I have tried many different variations of the query to try and send it to my localhost wampserver.  If you see something I missed please let me know. Thanks!

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "databaseimage") or die('Error Connecting.');
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `images` (name,size,type,datetime,lat,long) VALUES ($imageName,$imageSize,$imageType,$datetime,$lat,$long)";
 if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Added to database successfully!";
 } else {
    echo "Error sending query!";
    printf("\nErrormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
 }
```

I have tried it with and without `` marks.
I have tried it with single quotes around each variable.
I have tried just sending raw data through and it still errors out.

Comment: Ok, try adding single quotes on string variables, like: VALUES ('$imageName',$imageSize,'$imageType',etc..)

Comment: The issue is with `long`

Comment: You should really use prepared statements instead of injecting your variables (unquoted...) in your sql statement.

Comment: prepare them like using PDO?

Answer (score 4):

LONG is a mySQL reserved word:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

One way to fix it is to wrap those words in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `images` (name,size,type,datetime,lat,`long`) VALUES ('$imagename'....
```

But it's much better practice to avoid using reserved words as column or table names if you can - as you've discovered, it leads to odd situations like this.

Comment: I did what you said and got this...  Errormessage: Unknown column 'jpeg.jpg' in 'field list'

Comment: You'll also need to use single quotes around column values - I've updated the answer. You should look at moving to mysqli_*or PDO, though; both will help you write SQL that's a lot more secure.

Comment: Ah, mea culpa - yes you are; you're not using prepared statements, though. Putting variables directly into your SQL can be dangerous - if there's an image with a quote in the name, it will break your SQL statement; and there are more malicious things possible than that.

Answer (score 0):

The query should look like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `images` (name,size,type,datetime,lat,`long`) VALUES ('$imageName',$imageSize,'$imageType','$datetime',$lat,$long)";
```